# How to create Well Formated Excel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I am looking for Creating Little Complex Excel as well as pdf document e.g. for invoice using asp.net and C# .

Can anyone suggest me any Library or Plugin which I can use for it.

Comment: If you want to pay for something, FlexCel from TMS can produce/report to Excel files very well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you get your data from database, for the Excel you could use `DataSet` Class and `GetXml` method of that class, then transform that XML into Excel XML using XSLT. I’ve been using that example: [How to transform a DataSet to spreadsheet XML for Excel by using Visual Basic .NET and ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319180) when I was developing similar functionality. That example is in Visual Basic, however it presents the concept which can be easily transferred to C#. I use that concept for generating downloadable XML also for generating email attachments.

The XSLT also allows applying formatting to the spreadsheet such as data-type, font-style, cell-borders, colors etc. One way to do it is to open new Excel document, format it to the desired look and save it to Excel XML. Then use the generated styles in the XSLT.

Comment: I will give a try and let you know, thanks for the solution. Is there any way to create pdf as well

Comment: [This](http://www.pdfsharp.net/Features.ashx) one looks promising because can import xml so you could use the same xml object for your excel and pdf. But, unable to say more because haven’t been using that technology.

Comment: At a glance, pdfsharp looks perfect for my requirements. Thanks one again.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used this, [CreateExcelFile](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm), a very easy-to-use library. It makes it very easy and convenient to generate Excelfiles to the client.